# Determining Longest run of Heads and Tails

Tags: python

I have a question about my fourth function, `LongestRun`. I want to output what the longest run of heads was and the longest run of tails based on how many flips (n) the user enters. I have tried a ton of different things, and it doesn't seem to work. Can you guys help me out?:

```
def LongestRun(n):
    H = 0
    T = 1
    myList = []
    for i in range(n):
        random.randint(0,1)
        if random.randint(0,1) == H:
            myList.append('H')
        else:
            myList.append('T')
```

I want this next piece to output two things.

1. "The longest run of heads was: " And then whatever the longest run
   of heads was.
2. "The longest run of tails was: " and whatever the longest run of
   tails was.

Please help me! Thank you guys!

Comment: when you append, have a counter that counts each results? `+=`

Comment: The random.randint() on line 6 is not necessary, you should remove it

Answer (score 4):

```
from itertools import groupby
my_list = [1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1]
max(len(list(v)) for k,v in groupby(my_list) if k==1)
```

is a fun way to group consecutive values and then counts the longest length of 1's, if you were to use "H/T" instead just change the if condition at the end

Comment: A slight abuse of groupby!

Comment: You have an extra "=" sign in my_list assignment

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the longest sequence as you go, resetting each sequence after comparing the current to the longest sequence:

```
def LongestRun(n):
    my_t, my_h = 0, 0
    long_h, long_t = 0, 0
    for i in range(n):
        if not random.randint(0, 1):
            my_h += 1
            # if we have heads, check current len of tails seq and reset
            if my_t > long_t:
                long_t = my_t
            my_t = 0
        else:
            # else we have tails, check current len of heads seq and reset
            my_t += 1
            if my_h > long_h:
                long_h = my_h
            my_h = 0
    print("Longest run of heads was {}\nLongest run of tails was {}".format(long_h, long_t))
```

Output:

```
In [4]: LongestRun(1000)
Longest run of heads was 11
Longest run of tails was 13

In [5]: LongestRun(1000)
Longest run of heads was 7
Longest run of tails was 10

In [6]: LongestRun(1000)
Longest run of heads was 13
Longest run of tails was 8
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a way with higher performance than my solution, but it gets you what you want:

You can do the following also with lists instead of np.arrays:

```
import numpy as np
n = 100
choices = ['H', 'T']
HT_array = np.random.choice(choices, n)  # creates a n dimensional array with random entries of H and T

max_h = 0
max_t = 0
count_h = 0
count_t = 0
for item in HT_array:
    if item == 'H':
        count_h += 1
        count_t = 0
        if count_h > max_h:
            max_h = count_h
    elif item == 'T':
        count_t += 1
        count_h = 0
        if count_t > max_t:
            max_t = count_t
```

print(max_t)
print(max_h)

Answer (score 0):

My not so optimized version:

```
def LongestRun(myList, lookFor='H'):
    current_longest = 0
    max_longest = 0
    for x in myList:
        if x == lookFor:
            current_longest+=1
            if current_longest > max_longest:
                max_longest = current_longest
        else:
            current_longest=0
    return max_longest

myList = 'H H H H H T H T H T T H T T T T T T H H H H H H H H H H H H H T'.split()
print LongestRun(myList)
print LongestRun(myList, 'T')
```

Answer (score 0):

As @khuderm suggested, one solution is to have a counter that keep track of of the current run of heads or tails and two variables that keep track of the max run for each one.

Here's what the process should look like:

1. Initialize `counter`, `max_H` and `max_T` to zero,
2. Each time you append a `'H'` or `'T'`, increment `counter` by 1
3. After incrementing `counter`, if corresponding max is less than `counter`, update max to the value of `counter`.
4. Finally, if the previous flip was a `'H'` and now its a `'T'` or vice vera, reset `counter` to zero.